# Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am doing following test and got JNI error. This happened with TestNG, I can run this test with with 
    public void main(String[] args) but not with TestNG.

package restAssurePractice;

```
    import io.restassured.RestAssured;
    import io.restassured.http.ContentType;

    import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
    import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ApiBasics {

    @Test

    public static void restAssuredVerification() {

        //baseurl
        RestAssured.baseURI="https://reqres.in/";

        given().
            param("page=2").

        when().

        get("/api/users").

        then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.JSON).and().
        body("data[0].last_name",equalTo("Michael"));

    }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Where is the "JNI error"?

Comment: I know this is little bit unrelated, but if you want to take a look at how can you run JUnit tests of JNI based code (JUnit and googletests) take a look here: https://gitlab.com/mkowsiak/converter-docker and here https://gitlab.com/mkowsiak/converter (these two projects are linked together)